# How to save added data from HTML Table to SQL (PHPMYADMIN)

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

So here is my situation; I'm trying to save the data from the table which is added by filling up the form, I don't know how to save this to my database in phpmyadmin using javascript or ajax. A sample code is deeply appreciated. Thanks! PS: I'm a beginner, I'm just scraping the internet for code and trying to make do of what I get. Please Help :D

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class = "inputfield">
 <label>First Name:</label>
 <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
 <label>Last Name:</label>
 <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
 <label>Gender:</label>
 <select name="gender" id="gender">
  <option>Male</option>
  <option>Female</option>
 </select><br>
 <label>HOURS:</label>
 <input type="number" min=".5" max="12" step=".5" name="hours" id="hours" placeholder="--.5 to 12--"> <br>
</div>
<div class = "tablefield">
 <table class="mtable"  id="mtable">
  <tr>
   <th width="27%">First Name</th>
   <th width="27%">Last Name</th>
   <th width="15%">Gender</th>
   <th width="15%">Hour</th>
   <th width="16%">Edit</th>
  </tr>
  
 </table>
 <table class="sumtable">
  <tr><b>
   <td class="sum">TOTAL HOURS</td>
   <td class="sum1" id="sumtd"></td>
  </b></tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button type = "button" onclick="add1('mtable')">ADD</button>
  <button type = "reset" name="reset" class="btnclr">CLEAR</button>
  <button type = "button" name="save" onclick="savefunc()">SAVE</button>
</div>
<input type = "hidden" name="hid1" id="hid1">
<input type = "hidden" name="hid2" id="hid2">
<input type = "hidden" name="hid3" id="hid3">
<input type = "hidden" name="hid4" id="hid4">

<script>
var sum = 0;

function add1(){
 "use strict";
 var hour1 = document.getElementById("hours").value;
 sum = parseFloat(sum)+ parseFloat(hour1);
 document.getElementById("sumtd").innerHTML = sum;
 var table = document.getElementById("mtable"),rindex2;
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var td3 = document.createElement('td');    
 var td4 = document.createElement('td');    

 var element1 = document.createElement("Button");
        element1.type = "button";
        element1.name = "btnedit";
  element1.innerHTML = "Update";
  element1.setAttribute('class','btnedit');
 var element2 = document.createElement("Button");
        element2.type = "button";
        element2.name = "btndel";
  element2.innerHTML = "Delete";
  element2.setAttribute('class','btndel');
  
  for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
  element1.onclick = function () {
  try { 
  rindex2 = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
  sum = parseFloat(sum) - parseFloat(table.rows[rindex2].cells[3].innerHTML);
  console.log(rindex2);
  this.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  this.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  this.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("gender").value;
  this.parentNode.cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("hours").value;
  sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("hours").value);
  document.getElementById("sumtd").innerHTML = sum;
  }catch(e){
   alert(e);
  }};
   
  element2.onclick = function () {
  try {
  rindex2 = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
  console.log(rindex2);
  sum = parseFloat(sum) - parseFloat(table.rows[rindex2].cells[3].innerHTML);
  document.getElementById("sumtd").innerHTML = sum;
  table.deleteRow(rindex2);
  }catch(e){
   alert(e);
  }};

  }
    td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 td2.innerHTML  = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    td3.innerHTML  = document.getElementById("gender").value;
 td4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("hours").value;
 
 row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
 row.appendChild(td4);
 row.appendChild(element1);
 row.appendChild(element2);
    table.children[0].appendChild(row); 
}
function savefunc(){
 var table1 = document.getElementById("mtable");
 var hid1 = document.getElementById("hid1").value;
 var hid2 = document.getElementById("hid2").value;
 var hid3 = document.getElementById("hid3").value;
 var hid4 = document.getElementById("hid4").value;
 
 for (var r = 1, n = table1.rows.length; r < n; r++){
  var c0 = table1.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML;
  var c1 = table1.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML;
  var c2 = table1.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML;
  var c3 = table1.rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML;
  var c4 = table1.rows[r].cells[4].innerHTML;
  hid1 = c0;
  hid2 = c1;
  hid3 = c2;
  hid4 = c3;
  console.log(hid1);
  console.log(hid2);
  console.log(hid3);
  console.log(hid4);
 }
}




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi thanks but do you have any idea how can i integrate that to my code? thanks.

Comment: Got some ideas about `Get values from html table` with `jQuery ajax`, its not something I can be involved in .lol, I will follow and will be glad to see the result. I can only offer you some links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455876/get-value-from-html-table-input-cell-with-javascript and here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805288/jquery-get-values-from-html-table THIS ONE is with C# will give you and idea HOW TO get values and send values to function : https://forums.asp.net/t/2126891.aspx?How+to+loop+my+html+table+to+insert+values+into+database

Comment: Yes I already figure it out. thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure it out. i just include this on the bottom of my loop statement and added a save.php file. Use this as reference https://www.studentstutorial.com/ajax/insert-data

```js
 
$.ajax({
   url: "save.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
    fname: hid1,
    lname: hid2,
    gender: hid3,
    hour: hid4
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(dataResult){
     var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
     if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
      alert("Save Successful!");
     }
     else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
        alert("Error occured !");
     }
    }
  });
```